# SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1 in Node

Tags: node.js

In Nodejs, I am trying to parse json data in node http.createServer post request. I am following [this](https://itnext.io/how-to-handle-the-post-request-body-in-node-js-without-using-a-framework-cd2038b93190) tutorial and written followig code.

```
var data;
req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data = JSON.parse(chunk.toString()); // parsing request body json object
});
req.on('end', function() {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Where I am parsing data, it is giving me syntax error `SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1`

I have also tried converting this line into following.

```
var data, value = {};
req.on('data', chunk => {
    value = chunk.toString(); // parsing request body json object
    data = JSON.parse(value);
});
```

Comment: What are you getting if you console.log(chunk) right before the parse?

Comment: @NickHolden It is buffer array and we to toString it to get it back in original json format.

Comment: I think you need ```data += JSON.parse(chunk.toString());```. You're replacing the chunk each time data arrives.

Comment: Depending on how your data is chunked, you may get invalid JSON in a chunk meaning you'll need to call `JSON.parse` only when you have all the data.